# Why do I get `Couldn't match expected type` in this Haskell code?

Tags: haskell

I have a function that works fine:

```
      z::Int->Int->[Char]
      z x y =show(x)++show(y)++show(x*y)
```

It's really just a function that convert some numbers into a string.
Then I quicksort the string with my quick sort function.

```
quicksort.z 2 3
```

but here I get the error

```
Couldn't match expected type `a0 -> [a1]' with actual type `[Char]'
In the return type of a call of `z'
In the second argument of `(.)', namely `z 2 3'
In the expression: flagskib . z 2 3
```

I tried fixes like parentheses and use of the $ function, but no help.

I appreciate any words on it. The problem is already fixed so the whole meaning of this post is to learn.

Answer (score 9):

`quicksort` takes one argument. `z` takes two. The composition operator has the following type

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
```

Perhaps you can see the problem now. The types do not match up.

```
quicksort $ z 2 3
```

Will work. So will `quicksort . z 2 $ 3` or similarly `(quicksort . z 2) 3` because the application of `z` to the argument `2` returns a function of one argument, which matches the type of `(.)` (partial application).

Answer (score 6):

I'm assuming `quicksort` has type`[a] -> [a]`.
`(.)` is used for function composition, thus it expects two functions to compose but you use a `[Char]` instead. What you wrote is equivalent to `\x -> quicksort ((z 2 3) x)`, which obviously doesn't work.
You should use `($)` instead, right-associative function application: `quicksort $ z 2 3`, equivalent to `quicksort (z 2 3)`.